# How to Change the position of searchbar in odoo 15 in web

Tags: python, odoo, erp, qweb, odoo-15

```
<t t-inherit="web.Legacy.ControlPanel" t-inherit-mode="extension" owl="1">  
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_cp_searchview')]" position="after">
      <div class="my-search">Test Search</div> 
    </xpath>   
</t>
```

How Can I change the position of the search bar?

I need to change base layout in 3 section

1. Sidebar Menu
2. Search menu
3. Page layout

How this possible in web odoo 15